# No volume groups found after restoring CentOS image to VirtualBox VM

Tags: centos, boot, virtual-machine

I used Clonezilla to backup an HP Proliant server running CentOS 5.10. I restored the image to a VirtualBox VM but when I try to boot I get an error of "No volume groups found" "Volume Group "VolGroup00" not found" and then the kernel panics:

[image]

I gather the bootloader is looking for a volume that has probably been renamed by Clonezilla or doesn't exist. So to fix this do I need to change the fstab to look for the correct volumes or something more complex?

Comment: I sure hope it didn't rename anything. You can try booting into rescue mode doing a `pvscan` followed by a `vgchange -ay` after which you should be able to see whether `/etc/fstab` and the actual names differ.

Comment: 6 years later I'm hoping this is no longer an issue for you - I came across this after experiencing the same error after a V2V. I suspect it may be to do with the SCSI card emulation. but struggling to find a way to resolve this.